# Ratio of two independent noncentral $\chi^2$ random variables

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-distribution

I have to find out the distribution of the ratio of two independent noncentral $\chi^2$ random variables with means $\mu_1^2,\mu_2^2$. I know that if $\mu_2=0$, then the ratio has the noncentral $F$ distribution, but for the case when $\mu_2\ne 0$, is there any where in literature where I can find about this kind of distribution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610928608829120

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the paper appears no to be accessible.

Comment: Yes, behind a paywall.  Write the authors and ask for a preprint.

Comment: It is called the "doubly noncentral F-distribution". Wolfram lists it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NoncentralF-Distribution.html