# Distribution of ratio of $\bar X' \bar X$ and $\operatorname{tr}(S)$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

$X_{n\times p}\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $S$ is the sample variance-covariance matrix.

I was able to find out that $$(\bar X-\mu)^T (\bar X-\mu)/\operatorname{tr}(S)\sim{1\over n-1}F_{p,np-p}$$

since $\operatorname{tr}(S)\sim{\sigma^2\over n}\chi^2_{np-p}$ and $(\bar X-\mu)^T (\bar X-\mu)\sim{\sigma^2\over n}\chi^2_{p}$  independently. However I want to find out the distribution without the $\mu$ terms in numerator. Would that follow any known distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio of a non central chi square and a central chi square give rise to a non central F distribution.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_F-distribution

I'm not sure if there exist a known distribution for the rate of two non central chi squares.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196814.  However, in all these cases the numerator and denominator must be *independent.* Can you characterize when that would occur here?

Comment: If the result op posts actually hold for any variance covariance matrix then I don't see why it's non central equivalent wouldn't hold here.