# Regressing every variable against all others

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have $n$ observations of $m$ variables. I would like to regress each of the $m$ variables against the other $m-1$ variables.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this than running $m$ regressions?

Comment: "Regress"... What statistic(s) do you want exactly?

Comment: I believe that once you have computed the full covariance matrix, you can combine the $O(m^2)$ method of updating the inverse of the covariance matrix (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196814) with the $O(m^2)$ solution in terms of the inverse covariance at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107597.  Whether this is more efficient depends on how you are running the $m$ regressions.